# Maven shade plugin use

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven shade plugin and I referred some websites.I want some clarification on below questions.

1. what is the main difference between maven shade plugin and maven assembly plugin?
2. Which one is good for generating excutable jar?
3. In future, Whether will I face any issues or problems due to version changes?
4. I have been generated excutable jar using maven shade plugin.In pom.xml have 
   below lines.

   ```
     <filters>
           <filter>
             <artifact>*:*</artifact>
             <excludes>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
             </excludes>
           </filter>
   <filters>
   ```

why we are adding this in pom.xml? It is optional or else. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answers are:

1. Assembly plugin is generally for making `tar.gz` deployment bundles, shade plugin is for generating "uber" or executable `jar`.
2. For executable `jar` use shade.
3. No problems with different versions of the plugin.
4. Used for excluding certain things (like dev config) from the executable `jar`.

Comment: But,can I create excutable jar using assembly plugin? Is possible? Thanks